# Cannot resolve method 'push' in 'customMob'

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create a list of all my objects, but I keep getting the "Cannot resolve method 'push' in 'customMob' " error.

Here, the error is in the last line. I wanted to create a blank array with nothing in it and then add ENTITY_BOB to the array, but got an error.

```
public class customMobList {
    public static customMob[] mobList = new customMob[0];
    public static customMob ENTITY_BOB = new customMob("Bob", 10000, 999, false);

    public static void addMob() {
        mobList.push(ENTITY_BOB); <-- error here
    }
}
```

I tried writing a less complicated block of code to see if the same error occured:

```
public static int[] test = new int[0];
    public static void addInt() {
        test.push(1); <-- error here
    }
```

I got the error "Cannot resolve method 'push' "

Answer (score 0):

Java makes a distinction between *arrays* and *lists*. An array is an ordered group of elements whose size *cannot* be changed. So you can't add to one via a method like `push` or `add`. A `List`, on the other hand, is a data type that allows you to add/remove elements after you initialize it. (See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-vs-arraylist-in-java/# for more details).

Your code uses an array, but it would probably work best with a `List`. The most-used List implementation in Java is the `ArrayList` data structure (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html for more details).

If you were to use an ArrayList, your `mobList` declaration would look something like this:

```
public static ArrayList<customMob> mobList = new ArrayList<>();
```

And you can add elements to `mobList` using the `add` method (not `push` like in other languages):

```
mobList.add(ENTITY_BOB);
```

Also make sure to add `import java.util.ArrayList;` to the top of your source file!